# Deriving the algorithm for inverting a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

I've already read another answer here:
[Deriving inverse matrix formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1091818/deriving-inverse-matrix-formula)

However, this only covers $2\times 2$ matrices, disappointingly. I have checked Wikipedia and it has numerous methods for finding a matrix inverse. However, few (if any) of those methods include derivations for the method. Could anyone recommend a textbook which includes this (doesn't matter about the "level" of maths in the book, as long as it has it in).

I am currently reading Halmos' finite dimensional vector spaces, however this is mostly with the aim of understanding the theory behind matrices, determinants and inverse matrices, as well as preparing to learn machine learning and stats. If you feel this book would be enough, please let me know.

Comment: You most certainly don't want a formula for inverting a matrix greater than $2\times2$. If you write a matrix as an augmented matrix with itself on the left and the identity on the right, then row reduce the augmented matrix until you have the identity on the left you should be left with the inverse on the right; that is, assuming the matrix is invertible. Keyterm: Gauss-Jordan elimination.

Comment: Alternatively, it is quite straightforward to see that the adjugate matrix divided by the determinant is an inverse, so long as you really understand the cofactor expansion formula for the determinant

Comment: @Logan I never said formula, I said method. Furthermore, I asked for a derivation of the method, and a reference to read for said derivation/proof of the method.

Comment: @FShrike, thanks for the comment! Do you have any textbooks I could go through that explain _why_ the cofactor expansion formula for a determinant works? Ie, a proof/derivation of the formula/method? (Here I am saying formula because that is what FShike's statement appears to elude to).

Comment: There is nice proof on Wikipedia of both the Leibniz formula for determinants and the cofactor expansion

Comment: @Cai The first sentence in my comment wasn't implying that you wanted an explicit formula, just that they probably aren't the best answer to the question despite being reasonable for $2\times2$ matrices. Regarding your second comment, this is why I wrote a comment not an answer. Furthermore, I gave you a term to search, have you tried to find an answer to your question yourself yet?